# ASP.NET MVC code for graderoseter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner in programming and one of the classes that I'm taking is based on ASP.NET MVC. For one of the projects, we are supposed to create a GradeRoster but I cannot seem to run the program. I keep getting errors. It says that GradeRoster (it's typed like this in the program. I put the errors in single quotes. There are 7 in total) is supposed to be used as a namespace but is used as a type. I have no idea what to do. Thank you for your help.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
using GradeRoster.Models;

namespace GradeRoster.Controllers
{
    public class GradeRosterController : Controller
    {
        private GradeRosterContext db = new GradeRosterContext();

        // GET: /GradeRoster/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.GradeRoster.ToList());
        }

        // GET: /GradeRoster/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            'GradeRoster' graderoster = db.GradeRoster.Find(id);
            if (graderoster == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(graderoster);
        }

        // GET: /GradeRoster/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: /GradeRoster/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="StudentID,Name,Test1,Test2,FinalExam,Projects,FinalGrade")] 'GradeRoster' graderoster)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.GradeRoster.Add(graderoster);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(graderoster);
        }

        // GET: /GradeRoster/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            'GradeRoster' graderoster = db.GradeRoster.Find(id);
            if (graderoster == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(graderoster);
        }

        // POST: /GradeRoster/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="StudentID,Name,Test1,Test2,FinalExam,Projects,FinalGrade")] 'GradeRoster' graderoster)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(graderoster).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(graderoster);
        }

        // GET: /GradeRoster/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            'GradeRoster' graderoster = db.GradeRoster.Find(id);
            if (graderoster == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(graderoster);
        }

        // POST: /GradeRoster/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            'GradeRoster' graderoster = db.GradeRoster.Find(id);
            db.GradeRoster.Remove(graderoster);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `GradeRoster` with `GradeRoster.Models.GradeRoster`.

I'm guessing that's where the class is.

The problem is that GradeRoster immediately resolves into a namespace, but the C# compiler needs a class there. Another way to fix this would be to name the class something different, for example `GradeRosterModel`.